# Passenger error accessing PG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm using Bitnami Rails & PG stacks, Apache and Passenger.

I'm getting this error from Passenger:

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::Error)
```

I'm thinking that it's because Passenger isn't launching the production environment.

I added the RailsEnv production to my httpd.conf file, so it now reads like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName ndeavor.ameipro.com
RailsEnv production
DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/projects/ndeavor/releases/20130305221240/public
<Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/ndeavor/releases/20130305221240/public>
Allow from all
Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I tell if Passenger is trying to launch the Rails production environment?

Thanks!

Comment: Passenger always spawns an application under production. http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rails_env You should check your PG connection.

Comment: I ran this successfully $ rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load

Comment: I figured it out - dumb me, I was pointing to the wrong release folder.  Now I need to figure out how Capistrano can change the httpd.conf file when I do a new cap deploy.

Comment: Set the document root to the `current` symlink that capistrano creates with each `cap deploy`